Adjusting individual values of a dependent variable
I have a dataset including 600 pulse wave velocity readings that I need to adjust for each participant's mean arterial blood pressure. I can get so far as this:
m <- lm(pulse_wave_velocity ~ mean_arterial_bp, data = df)

Do I then use the residuals from the model to calculate the adjusted pulse wave velocity, and if so should they be added to the intercept?

Usually, one would use the PWV to determine the mean BP. But you seem to try to go in the reverse direction? Can you clarify what you mean by "adjust?

I want to look at the PWV of individuals, with the impact of individuals' blood pressure - which is  one of the most important contributing factors to PWV - negated/adjusted for. Does that make sense?

So you want to see if there is a correlation between PWV and BP. Let's say that there is, and that you find a significant linear regression; how would you then "adjust" the PWV? And why would you want to "adjust" it?

There is a correlation between BP and PWV: I want to try and get values of PWV from my participants in which the effect of BP is adjusted for so I can look at this parameter of cardiovascular health without the effects of BP 'interfering'. I have read that using the residuals after regressing PWV on BP will give me an adjusted PWV to work with

Do you have a link, or reference, for what you read? The residuals of a OLS of BP vs. PWV (and vice-versa) will sum to 0,  and thus their average. Are you sure you want the average "adjusted" PWV's to be 0 (which implies there will be negative values)? One could think of the residuals as an "excess" (or deficit) of PWV vs. the BP-predicted PWV? If this "delta PWV" makes sense clinically, why not? Most of the papers I know of are trying to use PWV to predict BP w/o a cuff.
